# EOL while scanning string literal error in my code

Tags: python, eol

```
File "C:\Users\RAJDEEP\Desktop\FINAL\preprocessed.py", line 10
source_dir=r'C:\Users\RAJDEEP\Desktop\FINAL\original_images\' +class_name
                                                                         ^
```

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape blackslashes. You can use (only on Windows!):

```
import os
os.path.join(r"C:\Users\RAJDEEP\Desktop\FINAL\preprocessed.py", class_name)
```

more on this "feature" of raw strings: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash

For example:

```
>>> source_dir=r'C:\Users\RAJDEEP\Desktop\FINAL\original_images' '\\' + class_name
>>> source_dir
'C:\\Users\\RAJDEEP\\Desktop\\FINAL\\original_images\\test'
>>> print(source_dir)
C:\Users\RAJDEEP\Desktop\FINAL\original_images\test
```

which is a better and portable solution.

```
source_dir=r'C:\Users\RAJDEEP\Desktop\FINAL\original_images' '\\' + class_name
```

is equivalent to

```
source_dir=r'C:\Users\RAJDEEP\Desktop\FINAL\original_images' + '\\' + class_name
```